# How to augment list from one module to another and add leafs YANG

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

Suppose I have two modules, I would like to extend one list with new leafs.

```
module A {
    list deviceList {
        key name;
        leaf name{

        }
        leaf hostname{

        }
    }
}
```

and I would like to augment it to another leaf

```
module B {
    list generalInfo{
        key customerName;
        leaf customerName{
            type string;
        }
        augment moduleA:deviceList {
            leaf ipAddress{
                
            }
        }
}
```

I have done it using grouping and container and list inside but this completely changes our existing structure, I would like to ommit container and grouping if thats possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to reuse a part of the schema definition, put it in another place in the schema tree and add a node to it.

You cannot do it the way you tried because the `augment` statement can appear only on the root level or in the `uses` statement.

You can do that only with a `grouping` but you can omit the `container`. Refactor A: define a `grouping` that's a `list`. Refer to it in B and augment it.

```
module A {
    grouping devices {
      list deviceList {
        key name;
        leaf name{
        }
        leaf hostname{
        }
      }
    }
    uses devices;
}

module B {
    list generalInfo{
        key customerName;
        leaf customerName{
            type string;
        }
        uses moduleA:devices {
          augment "deviceList" {
            leaf ipAddress{
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you use the `augment` statement in the module B then it means that any device implementing module B has to also implement module A and its root-level `list deviceList`.  See [RFC 7950 4.2.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-4.2.8):

> When a server implements a module containing an "augment" statement,
> that implies that the server's implementation of the augmented module
> contains the additional nodes.

I am not sure if this is what you want. If not, then move the grouping definition to a module that contains only grouping definitions (without any "data definition statements") and import it from both A and B.